# MockAnalyzer in Lucene: attach stemmer or any custom filter?

Tags: unit-testing, lucene

The code for unit-testing is briefly this:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new MockAnalyzer(random, MockTokenizer.SIMPLE, true);
rd = newDirectory();
IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(rd, newIndexWriterConfig(TEST_VERSION_CURRENT, analyzer));
```

I would like to be able to configure my own custom filters and add PorterStemmer filter to this configuration. Is it possible to do it with the MockAnalyzer class or should some other class be used for the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer to this from Robert Muir:

`MockAnalyzer` is really just `MocKTokenizer` + `MockTokenFilter` + ...

Instead you just define your own analyzer chain using `MockTokenizer`.
This is the way all Lucene's own analysis tests work: e.g.
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/analysis/common/src/test/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/TestEnglishMinimalStemFilter.java

For 3.4, extend `ReusableAnalyzerBase`.